# Javascript Image Zoom

Tags: javascript

I tried to implement the JavaScript Image Zoom from http://valid.tjp.hu/tjpzoom/

But as my customer requested, it has to run in IE 10. But the Thing is, it runs only in compatibility mode.

Is there a quick hack to fix it? I did not provide any sample, because it is also broken on the Website mentioned above.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried, before turing to this site for help? show some code, [and read the help section](http://stackoverflow/help), to see what makes a good question

Comment: remove the filters from the style tags

Comment: The page you reference contains this paragraph `If something doesn't work as expected, send me the url of the page where you see the problem. My address is valid@tjp.hu. I hope we can fix it together.`, try following that advice ;)  I think he might know more than we do about this.

Comment: @DavidMårtensson, @EliasVanOotegem, @andrewmu, @Joe, @WATTOStudios This question is closed by reason `Too Broad` after the answer is accepted by OP. Seems vague reason for closing when op has accepted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` to head of your webpage, make sure it is first meta tag in head. e.g.

```
<head id="Head" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <%--other code goes here--%>
</head>
```

This will open the page in compatibility mode, you can also use IE=8 or IE=Edge(Latest available)

Comment: This would be a work around. I think it should work in standards mode only.

Comment: Yes, this is a work-around as mentioned in question, need quick hack fix and it runs only in compatibility mode.

Comment: Thanks, did what I asked for!